# Create a singlepart polygon with several polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to create one polygon including others polygons that has an `ID < 16` .

[image]

The yellow polygons have `ID < 16` and I would like to create a polygon like this:
[image]

**EDIT : I do not want to get a multipart polygon, but a singlepart polygon and fill the spaces in between.**

Probably not a good idea, but polygons being always alligned by ascendant numbering (  1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - ...) , a logics could be to join polygon ID 1 to the polygon ID 2, then the polygon ID 2 to the polygon ID 3, etc. by joinning the closest corners to the next ID polygon.

I've no idea how to accomplish this task, is there a way to automatize it?

EDIT :
**the aim is to have only one polygon at the end**

Comment: I've edited my question in order to add a logics of numbering, I thought it could be helpfull?

Comment: and the answer of your question is yes, I need to keep only polygons that match with a condition depending of the value of the field

Comment: Crete a new field with an expression like this `if("ID" < 16, -1, $id)` this will set all the features with `ID < 16` to -1 and any other values to the feature id (which is unique). Then dissolve by this new field.

Comment: ok this could be the first step, but my need is to have 1 polygon that include all fields with ID < 16

Comment: What more do you need than what Mayos answer gives you? That will make a new layer with exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I made a mistake in my last answer : it should have been : "ok this could be the first step, but my need is to have 1 polygon that include all POLYGONs with ID < 16"

Comment: The point of this topic is to create a new polygon as you can see in the second screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select by expression with the expression `ID < 16`
2. `Merge Selected Features`

[image]

To further proceed to fill the space between the parts of the merged polygon to get a contiguous single-part polygon, you can use concave hull:

3. [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices) (you might use this with `Selected features only`, then you can skip step 2 from above).
4. Run *Menu Processing > Toolbox > [Concave Hull (alpha shapes)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-alpha-shapes)* on the vertices layer. Set an appropriate value for Threshold - in my case, 0.14 produced the result shown below.

*The pink polygon represents the output of Concave Hull (alpha shapes):*
[image]

Comment: thanks for this proposal but it merges the entities, but doesn't merge polygons.
My aim is to have only 1 polygon at the end.

Comment: What do you mean by "entities"? The solution indeed creates just one (merged) polygon, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: When I open the "Attribut table" of this layer , there is only 1 row (1 entity), but visualy, I see several polygons. Is it more clear?

Comment: for exemple, when you look at the second screenshot I sent into the question, there is only 1 brown polygon

Comment: OK, then you mean features (not "entities"). You want to  get not a multipart, but a singlepart polygon and fill the spaces in between. Filling the space is a rather different thing than just "merging" polygons.

Comment: thanks, now I need to batch this function with condition, I'm going to create a new topic !

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to batch this function with a loop, in a virtual layer 
If you have an idea how to do, or if it is possible, this is the post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463154/create-polygons-using-a-loop-in-virtual-layer