# Create polygons using a loop in virtual layer

Tags: qgis, sql, loop, virtual-layer

I would like create singlepart polygons including polygons from layer *Polygons* which have the same value in their row *unique_number*, and fill the spaces in between.
It will result several polygons : 1 polygon for every single value in the row *unique_number*.

I'm able to do it manually like it is describe in this answer:
[Create a singlepart polygon with several polygons in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437633/create-a-singlepart-polygon-with-several-polygons-in-qgis)
following this workflow :

1. Select by expression with the expression
2. Extract vertices Run Menu
3. Processing > Toolbox > **Concave Hull (alpha shapes)**

The problem is that instead of selecting 1 expression (step 1.) at time, I need to do this for every unique value (a loop) in the row : *unique_number* from layer *Polygons*