# Create singlepart polygons with several polygons in virtual layer QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer

I would like to automatize the creation of several **singlepart polygons** when polygons (from layer *Polygons*) are crossed by a the same polyline (from layer *polylines*), and fill the gap between [like describe there](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437633/create-a-singlepart-polygon-with-several-polygons-in-qgis).

[image]

I'm able to do it manually using this workflow :

- Extract vertices Run Menu
- Processing > Toolbox > Concave Hull (alpha shapes) ,value for Threshold = 0.14

But in this case there are several polylines, so it results the virtual layer should create several polygons (not only 1 as I do manually)

**EDIT :**

```
SELECT ST_UNION(pa.geometry) AS geometry
FROM Polygons AS pa, (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, geometry
    FROM Polylines
) AS pla
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(pa.geometry, pla.geometry)
GROUP BY pla.id
```

For every single polyline (from layer *Polylines*), this code create a polygon : this is almost what I need.
But the problem is that it creates multipart polygons, and it doesn't fill the gap between them.
That's why I think *Concave Hull (alpha shapes) ,value for Threshold = 0.14* would solve the issue, but I've no idea how to adapt the code with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test-setup:

1. Line-Memory-Layer with test-lines, Layername: Polylines
2. Polygon-Layer with id-column and Test-Polygons. Layername: Polygons.

I created a virtual layer in the QGIS DB-Manager with this query:

See attached screenshots.

```
with

line_layer_with_id as
(
     select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as line_id, geometry
     FROM Polylines l
),

intersect_subquery as 
    (
     select l.line_id, ST_UNION(p.geometry) as geometry FROM
          Polygons p, line_layer_with_id l
      where
        ST_Intersects(p.geometry, l.geometry)
        GROUP BY l.line_id
    ),

extract_vertices as
    (
    SELECT
         line_id, CastToMultiPoint(ST_Union(ST_DissolvePoints( sub.geometry))) as geometry
        FROM
        
          intersect_subquery sub
          GROUP BY line_id)
    select line_id, st_concavehull(ev.geometry, 5) as geometry
    from extract_vertices ev
    GROUP BY line_id;
```

You probably have to test some settings for the concavehull parameter and the optional boolean parameter if you want to allow holes or not. ( st_concavehull(ev.geometry, 2.5,False) for example )
[image]

Comment: hi, and thanks for answer.
In order to work without  the need of ID colomn, I use : ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id
But in your code, I do not know what can I change to make it working?

Comment: @zlikotp: therefore just replace the 3rd line with          
 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id , p.geometry FROM         
instead of      
select p.id, p.geometry FROM

Comment: @Tomas B: the code works but it creates only 1 multipart polygon instead of several singlepart polygon (1 polygon for every polyline). I've added my initial post with screenshoots of the result I get with your code.

Comment: @zlikotp: I changed the answer to allow generating one convexhull for every intersecting line. just try to adjust the convexhull parameter so it fit's the best for your datasets.

Comment: I tried with replacing  select l.id , ST_UNION(p.geometry) as geometry FROM by  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id , ST_UNION(p.geometry) as geometry FROM , but I get the same issue : "Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column: l.id"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147317/discussion-between-thomas-b-and-zlikotp).

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that your concavity factor works for you, it's a simple call to [`ST_ConcaveHull`](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html#p14c) you're missing:

```
SELECT
  line.id,
  ST_ConcaveHull(
    ST_Collect(poly.geometry),
    0.14
  ) AS geometry
FROM
  Polygons AS poly
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
      geometry
    FROM
      Polylines
  ) AS line ON
    ST_Intersects(poly.geometry, line.geometry)
GROUP BY
  line.id
;
```

or simpler - but not necessarily faster:

```
SELECT
  line.id,
  ST_ConcaveHull(
    ST_Collect(poly.geometry),
    0.14
  ) AS geometry
FROM
  Polygons AS poly
  JOIN
  Polylines AS line ON
    ST_Intersects(poly.geometry, line.geometry)
GROUP BY
  line.geometry
;
```

---

If those `Polygons` are strictly squares/rectangles like in your image there may be more performant, more precise workflows.

Comment: hello,
1) it doesn't create gemeotry : geometry is a row in attribute table, but entities doesn't have geometries. It results it doesn't display vectors.
2) about Row_Number : depending on the format of the vectors, some of them doesn't have ID auto. That's why I prefer always use Row_Number, to number bymyself the lines.
3) I'm very interested into more precise workflows, because my polygons are squares, so it could work perfectly !

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've edited my initial post, in order to show you the result on my screen.
as you can see, the icon of the layer "virtual layer" created by your code, doesn't display a polycon icon; also, the right windows is the attribute table which show an empty row geometry.

It results it doesn't display any vector as it should. any idea?

Comment: I wonder if we need to extract polygon geometry using : ST_CollectionExtract before the ST_ConcaveHull

Comment: it looks like ST_ConcavHull (alpha) need to work with points vectors. I guess we first have to extract vertices points from polygons, in order to use ST_ConcavHull , or we should reproduce the function "Concave hull (nearest neighboor) in order to directly work from polygon. 
Don't you think?